# Help w/translating (to English) a stamp on bowl please!

Tags: translation, character-identification, seal

[image]

[image]

Thanks for helping me with this!✌️

Comment: top is 东, cant really make out the rest

Answer (score 1):

I believe it says 东武.
Reference on the 2nd character: http://www.sfds.cn/6B66/5790852.html

So you bowl is either from 1648 东武, one of the Era names back in China
or...
related to 東武百貨 or Tobu Railway in Japan somehow...but I would guess the characters wouldn't be in simplified form

Hope this helped